# How to implement a Chat bubble shaped widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to design a widget of shape of a chat bubble where one corner is pinned and its height should adjust to the lines of the text? For now I'm using ClipRRect widget with some borderRadius. But I want one corner pinned. Any suggestions ? 
[image: Chat bubble shape]

**UPDATE**

I know this can be done using a stack but I'm looking for a better solution since I have to use it many times in a single view and using many stacks might affect the performs. ( correct me here if I'm wrong )

Comment: Regarding the update. Not much. You can minimize it. you don't need to paint the triangle every time. render your triangle once and save it on a variable. Even if you go 9patch images I'm afraid you'll need somewhat the same approach as a plain background image won't help you in this case

Comment: Check this  I used this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_superchat

Comment: I made a custom solution for implementing the chat bubble. Check this https://arkapp.medium.com/chat-bubble-widget-for-flutter-95d3bb82ddd8

Answer (score 5):

For someone who want this get done with library. You can add `bubble: ^1.1.9+1` (Take latest) package from pub.dev and wrap your message with Bubble.

```
Bubble(
style: right ? styleMe : styleSomebody,
//Your message content child here...
)
```

Here `right` is boolean which tells the bubble is at right or left, Write your logic for that and add the style properties `styleMe` and `styleSomebody` inside your widget as shown below. Change style according to your theme.

```
double pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
double px = 1 / pixelRatio;

 BubbleStyle styleSomebody = BubbleStyle(
      nip: BubbleNip.leftTop,
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 1 * px,
      margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 8.0, right: 50.0),
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    );

    BubbleStyle styleMe = BubbleStyle(
      nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
      color: Colors.grey,
      elevation: 1 * px,
      margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 8.0, left: 50.0),
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    );
```

Comment: Check this post for simple implementation - https://arkapp.medium.com/chat-bubble-widget-for-flutter-95d3bb82ddd8

Answer (score 4):

Hi im also searching for a chat bubble shaped widget finally i made one.
I have made this in custom Painter and i'm not good at it.
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatBubble extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;
  final Alignment alignment;

  ChatBubble({
    @required this.color,
    this.alignment,
  });

  var _radius = 10.0;
  var _x = 10.0;




  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (alignment == Alignment.topRight) {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
            0,
            0,
            size.width - 8,
            size.height,
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_radius),
            topRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(_radius),
          ),
          Paint()
            ..color = this.color
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
      var path = new Path();
      path.moveTo(size.width - _x, size.height - 20);
      path.lineTo(size.width - _x, size.height);
      path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
      canvas.clipPath(path);
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
            size.width - _x,
            0.0,
            size.width,
            size.height,
            topRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
          ),
          Paint()
            ..color = this.color
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
    } else {
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
            _x,
            0,
            size.width,
            size.height,
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
            topRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(_radius),
          ),
          Paint()
            ..color = this.color
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
      var path = new Path();
      path.moveTo(0, size.height);
      path.lineTo(_x, size.height);
      path.lineTo(_x, size.height-20);
      canvas.clipPath(path);
      canvas.drawRRect(
          RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
            0,
            0.0,
            _x,
            size.height,
            topRight: Radius.circular(_radius),
          ),
          Paint()
            ..color = this.color
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

copy and paste the **above** code and paste in your project

```
Align(
      alignment: alignment, //Change this to Alignment.topRight or Alignment.topLeft
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: ChatBubble(color: Colors.blue, alignment: alignment),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextView("Hello World"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

paste this code where you have to show chatBubble Widget.
And i have also upload this code in bitbucket [ChatBubble Widget](https://github.com/ditheshthegreat/FlutterChatBubble) Please be free if you have anything to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am not able to show you the code for it but I can present an idea that might work if you implement it correctly. Suppose the Widget you made with `ClipRect` is called `MyChatBubbleRect`. Now, make another widget that draws a triangle using [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html), let's call it `MyChatBubbleTriangle`, of course fill it with same color as the chat bubble but you can use a different color initially for debugging. Now that we have two widgets we can stack 'em together on top of each other and using [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget over the `MyChatBubbleTriangle`. Something like this:

```
Stack(
  children : [
     MyChatBubbleRect(), // Maybe decrease the width a bit
     Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: MyChatBubbleTriangle()
     )
  ]
)
```

This is just  an idea I think you can pursue. Sorry couldn't provide the proper source code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had this idea too but it doesn't feel like the correct way. I think this could be done using a Customer Border or something. Lets see if others have different answers

Comment: Yeah you should be able to hard code it using a `CustomPainter` and make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Chat Body

```
DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
   ),
   child: Text("your message goes here"),
);
```

Make a custom Triangle

```
class ChatBubbleTriangle extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;

    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(-10, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 10);
    path.lineTo(10, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Use both of them within a stack wrapping `ChatBubbleTriangle` with `Positioned()` widget