# How make curved container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need make container with angle for chat messaging application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ALI.png)

```
return Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 100, right: 30, bottom: 50),
height: double.infinity,
width: double.infinity,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.white,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
    topRight: Radius.circular(10),
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)
  ),
  boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
    spreadRadius: 5,
    blurRadius: 7,
    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
    ),
  ],
  ),
```

Please help, how make it?

Comment: There is this package for flutter. Have a look: https://pub.dev/packages/bubble

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a Chat bubble shaped widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420825/how-to-implement-a-chat-bubble-shaped-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go, make a widget and call that widget for use.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 20,
          left: 20,
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 70,
          left: 300,
          child: CustomPaint(painter: triangle()),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
```

The custom paint, you can call the below widget.

```
class triangle extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;

    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(-10, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 10);
    path.lineTo(10, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now just edit the path as you like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my answer and adapted from [Flutter - ClipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257)

```
Container(
  margin:
      EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 100, right: 30, bottom: 50),
  height: 100,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    shape: MessageBorder(),
    shadows: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
),




class MessageBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final bool usePadding;

  MessageBorder({this.usePadding = true});

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions =>
      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: usePadding ? 20 : 0);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, 20));
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom,
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)))
      ..moveTo(30, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(0, 20)
      ..relativeLineTo(20, -20)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```